# Nuxt SSG generated slug route 404

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo, datocms

I'm having an issue when using Nuxt.js with Apollo (and DatoCMS) when generating the slugs on an SSG.

Locally this all works fine, and when I `npm run generate` it looks to be generating the routes, but when I visit the URL directly I get a 404. Could this be a server issue rather than a Nuxt issue?

```
ℹ Parsed 4 files in 0,0 seconds                                                                                                                            @nuxt/content 14:01:06
ℹ Full static generation activated                                                                                                                                       14:01:06
ℹ Generating output directory: dist/                                                                                                                                     14:01:06
ℹ Generating pages with full static mode                                                                                                                                 14:01:06
✔ Generated route "/password"                                                                                                                                            14:01:06
✔ Generated route "/"                                                                                                                                                    14:01:07
✔ Generated route "/projects/encinal-canyon"                                                                                                                             14:01:07
✔ Client-side fallback created: 200.html                                                                                                                                 14:01:07
✔ Static manifest generated
```

I have a nuxt-link to /projects/encinal-canyon which works fine but when I visit that URL directly it 404s.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So, just to be sure you have it as `target: static` and you're doing `yarn generate && yarn start` to try the route? Can you show us your code editor with the directories? Also, double check if the route do exist in the `dist` directory.

Comment: Also, try to drop your static website here and see if this one works: https://app.netlify.com/drop